# Solving the Lagrange PDE: $(y+z)p+(z+x)q=(x+y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

> I am supposed to solve the Lagrange PDE: $(y+z)p+(z+x)q=(x+y)$ where $p, q$ is the usual notation for $z_{x}, z_{y}$ respectively. Here is what I have done so far.

---

**Attempted Solutiion**

Auxiliary equations:

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\mathrm dx}{y+z}=\frac{\mathrm dy}{x+z}=\frac{\mathrm dz}{x+y}&\overset{(1,-1,0)}=\frac{\mathrm dx-\mathrm dy}{y-x} \\ &\overset{(1,0,-1)}=\frac{\mathrm dx-\mathrm dz}{z-x} \\ &\overset{(0,1,-1)}=\frac{\mathrm dy-\mathrm dz}{z-y}\end{aligned}$$

Solving these equations, I got the solution as under, but I'm not sure whether this is correct.$$\phi\left(\frac{z-x}{y-x},\frac{z-y}{z-x}\right)=0$$
Could someone clarify whether this is indeed the solution and whether the approach is proper. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct.
$$\phi\left(\frac{z-x}{y-x},\frac{z-y}{z-x}\right)=0$$
This a correct implicit form of solution.

Equivalently the solution can be expressed on various forms of implicit equations, for example :
$$\psi\left(\frac{z-x}{y-x},\frac{z-y}{y-x}\right)=0$$
$$z=x+(y-x)F\left(\frac{z-y}{y-x}\right)$$
$\phi,\psi,F$ are arbitrary functions. Etc.
In order to determine those functions some boundary condition must be specified.