# Find the general solution of (y+z)p + (z+x)q = x+y

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, lagrange-multiplier

I did see the solution to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4402880/solving-the-lagrange-pde-yzpzxq-xy) but I still have doubts.

The subsidiary equation for the question is dx/(x+y) = dy/(z+x) = dz(x+y)

There are two methods to solving pde in the form of Pp + Qq = R (or at least the two we've been told to use.) 
1) Method of grouping, where you take any two relations and solve them 
2) Lagrange Multiplier, where you use the relation ldx + mdy + ndz/(lP + mQ + nR) and multiply terms such that the denominator is zero.

Using these two methods alone, I'm not able to arrive at the solution that is:
[image]

Does anyone know how I should proceed, can you please explain?

Comment: What is there to doubt in the solution in the linked question? They just used componendo-divindendo on the various relations and then used the 'method of grouping' as you have called it.

Comment: @mattos wait how is it component dividendo? wouldn't there have been a + in the numerator then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the PDE is q(y+z)p + (z+x)q = x+y the "subsidiary equation" isn't dx/(x+y) = dy/(z+x) = dz(x+y) as you wrote but is : dx/(y+z) = dy/(z+x) = dz(x+y).

Search for a first characteristic equation :
$$\frac{dx}{y+z}=\frac{dy}{z+x}=\frac{dz}{x+y}=\frac{dx+dy+dz}{(y+z)+(z+x)+(x+y)}=\frac{dx-dy}{(y+z)-(z+x)}$$
$$\frac{dx+dy+dz}{2(x+y+z)}=\frac{dx-dy}{(y-x)}$$
$$\frac12\ln|x+y+z|=-\ln|x-y|+constant$$
Thus a first characteristic equation is :
$$(x+y+z)(x-y)^2=c_1$$
Seach for a second characteristic equation :
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{y+z}=\frac{dy}{z+x}=\frac{dx-dy}{(y+z)-(z+x)}=\frac{dx-dy}{(y-x)}\\
\frac{dy}{z+x}=\frac{dz}{x+y}=\frac{dy-dz}{(z+x)-(x+y}=\frac{dy-dz}{(z-y)}
\end{cases}\quad\implies\quad \frac{dx-dy}{(x-y)}=\frac{dy-dz}{(y-z)}$$
$$\ln|x-y|=\ln|y-z|+constant$$
Thus a second characteristic equation is :
$$\frac{x-y}{y-z}=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE on implicit form $f(c_1,c_2)=0$ :
$$f\left((x+y+z)(x-y)^2\:,\: \frac{x-y}{y-z}\right)=0$$
$f$ is an arbitrary function of two variables (until bondary condition be specified).

In addition : ANSWER TO A QUESTION RAISED IN COMMENTS.

From the property of equal fractions
$$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{E}{F}\quad\implies\quad \frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{E}{F}=\frac{c_1A+c_2C+c_3E}{c_1B+c_2D+c_3F}$$
With $A=dx\quad , \quad C=dy \quad , \quad E=dz \quad , \quad B=(y+z)\quad , \quad D=(z+x) \quad , \quad F=x+y \quad , \quad$ and with$\quad c_1=c_2=c_3=1$
$$\frac{dx}{y+z}=\frac{dy}{z+x}=\frac{dz}{x+y}=\frac{dx+dy+dz}{(y+z)+(z+x)+(x+y)}$$
Also
$$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}\quad\implies\quad \frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{c_1A+c_2C}{c_1B+c_2D}$$
with $A=dx\quad , \quad C=dy \quad ,  B=(y+z)\quad , \quad D=(z+x) \quad , \quad c_1=1\quad$and$\quad c_2=-1$
$$\frac{dx}{y+z}=\frac{dy}{z+x}=\frac{dx-dy}{(y+z)-(z+x)}$$

Comment: Hi Jean ! Long time no see. Are you OK ? Cheers

Comment: Hi Claude ! OK for me. What about you ? I hope you are well. Cheers -

Comment: i havent understood how we get the `++/(+)+(+)+(+)` part and the `−/(+)−(+)` from the 3 equalities. could you please explain?

Comment: Wellknown property of equal  fractions : If $\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}$ then $\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{c_1A+c_2C}{c_1B+c_2D}$ with arbtrary $c_1\:,\:c_2$.

Comment: Remember a wellknown property of fractions :
$$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{E}{F}\quad\implies\quad \frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{E}{F}=\frac{c_1A+c_2C+c_3E}{c_1B+c_2D+c_3F}$$
for arbitrary constants $c_1,c_2,c_3$ not all nul.

Comment: @JJacquelin thank you so much!